# Sybil detection metric

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, large-data, metric

I have a set of user data and I want to build some kind of metric to evaluate the probability of the user being a sybil (a "fake" account).

**But** I have a very limited set of users who are sybils with 100% certainty.

How do I use machine learning here?

Also, as for now, I've built a heuristic metric based on that data and need to evaluate it somehow.

**To sum up:** 
I have a small fraction of data that is labeled and only negative class. And need to build a metric to evaluate users. On top of that I need evaluate the "goodness" of that metric?

How do I approach this problem?

**ps** It would be good if I could scale this process for big datasets.

Comment: You need some examples of each class.  Maybe start with logistic regression, and try to extend it to case where not all individuals have a certain class identity.  Some ideas can be found here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174856/semi-supervised-classification-with-unseen-classes

Comment: You also find a lot about sybil detection by googling:  https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity13/technical-sessions/presentation/wang